# Restoring lost group permissions on mac

Tags: macos, mac, file-sharing, chmod

Using mac's terrible file sharing prefs, I managed to goof up permissions on my Documents directory.  My non-Documents directories have permissions like this:

```
drwx------+ for .
drwxr-xr-x+ for ..
-rw-------@ for .DS_Store

drwxr-xr-x  for most folders
drwxr-xr-x@ for some folders

-rw-r--r--  for some files
-rw-r--r--@ for some files
```

My Documents directories have permissions like this:

```
drwx---r-x+ for .
drwx---r-x+ for ..
-rw----r--@ for .DS_Store

drwx---r-x+ for (all?) folders

-rw----r--@ for some files
-rw----r--+ for some files
```

It looks like everything that should have group read access is missing it.  I realize that chmod can help, and that it has a -R recursive option, but I'm reluctant to start experimenting and mess things up more.  In particular, I don't want to set group read in places where it shouldn't be there.  Also, I want to change just some bits, leaving the others alone.

Can anyone provide advice about getting this fixed?

Not sure if it's relevant, but I got into this by trying to allow another user on the same machine read/write access to my main user's Documents.  In sharing prefs, I tried adding the  Documents folder to the list of shared folders and setting everyone to read (or at least read), but in the process, I think I deleted the "staff" group, whatever that is.

Comment: Ignore the `@`, that's just extended attributes. Run `ls -lae` to get the ACL information (indicated by `+`) that might override regular Unix permissions (they probably shouldn't be there except *maybe* on the Documents folder itself). Default permissions are 700 for the Documents folder, 755 for all contained folders, and 644 for all contained files (and we can probably ignore execute permissions). `staff` is the main group of all actual user accounts (as opposed to system internal users).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a pinch, you can add group read/write permissions by entering your Documents directory and issuing:

```
chmod -R g+rw *
```

If you need to fix the ownership you can do:

```
chown -R user.group *
```

[Obviously you replace `user` and `group` with actual an user and group name]

Now you just need to fix the directories.

```
find . -type d | replace ' ' '\ ' | xargs chmod g+x
```

The above call finds all directories, then escapes spaces with a backslash (required for passing to `xargs`), then adds group execute permissions to each.  The `replace` command is part of mysql.  If you don't have that you can use `sed 's/ /\\ /g'`

Disclaimer that my Linux distro is Slackware.  I would expect this to work on Mac, but I can't test.  You can replace `xargs chmod g+x` with `echo | more` if you want to do a sanity check.

Note that you can pipe the output to file first:

```
find . -type d | replace ' ' '\ ' > dirs.txt
```

Then you can review that file and use a text editor to remove any directories you don't want to change.  Then instead of the recursive calls to `chmod`, you can do:

```
cat dirs.txt | sed 's/$/\/*/' | xargs chmod g+rw
cat dirs.txt | xargs chmod +x
```

The `sed` call just replaces the end of each line with '/*' to mean all files in directory.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, the + attribute after the standard ls rwxrwxrwx signals ACLs.  I'd be careful because your group read access might be a part of the ACL scheme.